# Azure Managed MySQL

Tags: azure, azure-mysql-database

I am not able to find a way to create read-only replicas for MySQL in Azure Managed MySQL. Neither I can enable the binary logging in existing production instance. Is that a feauture Azure Managed MySQL does not provide?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is a feature-request discussion, not a programming question.

Comment: FYI you can upvote the [uservoice item](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/597982-azure-database-for-mysql/suggestions/19274365-active-geo-replication-like-sql-database) for georeplication. But today, there are no secondaries configurable. The database service itself provides a highly-available service, just not with accessible read replicas.